# How to connect multiple power rail wires together?

Tags: wiring, wire-terminals

I'm working on a project that uses a 12 V supply, tower light, buck converter & Raspberry Pi.

I am prototyping it on a breadboard, but want a permanent home for it in an enclosure.

What would be a good way to connect all the positive rail wires together & all the ground rail wires together?

I tried using the [Wago splicing connectors](https://www.wago.com/us/wire-splicing-connectors/compact-splicing-connector/p/221-415), but they seem more suited for "electrical" circuitry rather than the finer electronic circuitry.

Is there a best practice for connecting multiple rail wires together between boards?

Answer (score 1):

Terminal Strips are most common for pigtail wire bonding but in pairs demands a solid wire to connect up one side of the screw terminals by daisy-chain then to source.
_______|________|_________|___

Busbar connectors tend to be overkill $

[image] 
[REF](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/adafruit-industries-llc/737/1528-1520-ND/5774323) 7 load sides per pole but this one is cheap $2.80

[image]  [REF](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/amphenol-anytek/YK2110803000G/YK2110803000G-ND/4960729)  $2.30 (5)
Mount on FR4, wood or equiv. and bridge all pins together with AWG 16 solid gnd wire.

Comment: I've looked at them, they're just for joining one wire to another, I'm looking to connect multiple wires together similar to a "busbar" found in an electrical CU.

Comment: Call Digikey tech support

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for "choc block", a.k.a. terminal strip. You can common all the terminals with one piece of wire on one side in the screw terminals, then attach your individual power wires to the other side:

[image]

(Image from [screwfix.com](https://www.screwfix.com/p/6a-terminal-strips-pack-of-10/60804).)

There are holes between the terminals which you can use to fasten it to something. Also, it is easily cut apart between the terminals using a utility knife. It is cheap.

Best practice would be to use ferrules on the ends of the wires if they have stranded conductors.

Or you could do pretty much the same thing with tag connector strips.

Answer (score 1):

For actually connecting 3+ wires/nodes together (and not just joining individual sets of two), you can use the common screw terminal blocks along with a "strip" thing that bridges the connections. They can be easily cut to the desired numbers of terminals.

You can find block and strip sold together or separately.

[image: Screw terminal block with strip]

(Image from [ebay.com](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Power-Distribution-Terminal-Block-Ground-Wire-Bus-Bar-Electrical-Connectors-Tool/392302734175))

You could also just crimp your own wires together with terminals to function like the red strip above.